# Which is the faster way to remove a list of rows from huge log file using PHP

Tags: php, logging

I need to remove various useless log rows from a huge log file (200 MB)
`/usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log`

The useless log rows are in array `$useless`

The way I am doing is

```
$working_log="/usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log";        
foreach($useless as $row) 
{

    if ($row!="") {
        file_put_contents($working_log, 
            str_replace("$row","",  file_get_contents($working_log)));
    }
}
```

I need to remove about 65000 rows from the log file; 
the code above does the job but it works slow, about 0.041 sec to remove each row.

Do you know a faster way to do this job using php ?

Comment: hmm.... I don't think 0.041 seconds are slow for 65000 row.

Comment: BTW about 0.040 for each row, no about 0.040 for 65000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file can be loaded in memory twice (it seems it can if your code works) then you can remove all the strings from `$useless` in a single `str_replace()` call.

The documentation of [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function explains how:

> If `search` is an array and `replace` is a string, then this replacement string is used for every value of `search`.

```
$working_log="/usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log";
file_put_contents(
    $working_log,
    str_replace($useless, '', file_get_contents($working_log))
);
```

When the file becomes too large to be processed by the code above you have to take a different approach: create a temporary file, read each line from the input file and write it to the temporary file or ignore it. At the end, move the temporary file over the source file:

```
$working_log="/usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log";
$tempfile = "/usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log.new";

$fin  = fopen($working_log, "r");
$fout = fopen($tempfile, "w");
while (! feof($fin)) {
    $line = fgets($fin);
    if (! in_array($line, $useless)) {
        fputs($fout, $line);
    }
}
fclose($fin);
fclose($fout);

// Move the current log out of the way (keep it as backup)
rename($working_log, $working_log.".bak");
// Put the new file instead.
rename($tempfile, $working_log);
```

You have to add error handling (`fopen()`, `fputs()` may fail for various reasons) and code or human intervention to remove the backup file.